# Setup Project and Access Permission

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, permissions, setup-project

I created a setup project in VS2008. This setup copy some folders/files to the program files folder. Also, it adds some windows environment variables.
During the instalation, I am requested to confirm something in a UAC dialog.
This works fine, and all files are copied.

The problem begins when my program is running and I have to modify the a file´s content.
An exception is thrown, saying that I have no permission. Also, if I try to do the same operation in Windows Explorer => same problem.

My question is: 
If I have the permission to install my software in program files folder, shouldn´t I be able to write in this folder as well?

Comment: Are the files marked as Read-only? Also, when you run the application as admin, does the same issue arrise?

Comment: No files marked as read-only. Also, it is not possible to test the setup using admin credentials (due to external factors)

Comment: Does this permission error occurs for all files or only for the ones you add with the setup? Also what folders are you writing to?

Comment: I´m writing to program files, and this error occurs to all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that this is a general permission problem. By default normal users (and applications) cannot write to %PROGRAMFILES%. There are folders specially provided for application data storage such as [ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

The reason the setup does install into program files is because this default behaviour of the Windows Installer. Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4.aspx) for more info on the Windows Installer and clickonce setup